# Issue getting required output using LINQ query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core, linqpad

I need to get data as per this json format.

```
series: [{
    name: 'Marriage',
    data: [1, 2, 3] // Sample Data
}, {
    name: 'Chess',
    data: [2, 2, 3]
}, {
    name: 'Ludo',
    data: [3, 4, 4]
}]
```

I need to create chart as here in http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/bar-stacked/

What I have tried is using group by from device id and and using for loop to get the result. But I am quite stuck here getting required output.

Here is what I have tried so far.

```
void Main()
{
DateTime currentDate = DateTime.UtcNow.Date.AddDays(-30);
var currentMonthData = Device_GameDevices.Where(x => x.CreatedDate >= currentDate).ToList();
// Get total game list
var gamesList = currentMonthData.Select(x => x.GameName).Distinct();

// Group the data as per the device id
var groupedData = from gameData in currentMonthData
                  group gameData by gameData.DeviceID
                  into egroup
                  select new {
                      Game = egroup.Key,
                      Data = from bug in egroup
                               group bug by bug.GameName into g2
                               select new { Name = g2.Key, HoursPlayed = g2.Sum(x => (x.EndTime - x.StartTime).TotalMinutes/60) }
                  };

Console.Write(groupedData);

List<DashboardVM.ChartData> chartDatas = new List<DashboardVM.ChartData>();
List<double> hourResultList = new List<double>();

foreach(var item in groupedData)
{
    var chart = new DashboardVM.ChartData();
    foreach(var gameItem in gamesList)
    {
        chart.GameNameResult = gameItem;
        foreach(var groupedDataItem in item.Data)
        {               
            if(gameItem == groupedDataItem.Name)
            {
                hourResultList.Add(groupedDataItem.HoursPlayed);
            }
            else
            {
                hourResultList.Add(0.0);
            }
        }

        chart.HoursPlayed = hourResultList;
    }

    chartDatas.Add(chart);
}

Console.Write(chartDatas);
}

public class DashboardVM{
 public class ChartData{
    public string GameNameResult{get;set;}
    public List<double> HoursPlayed{get;set;}
 }
 }
```

Comment: How does the sample data you've provided correspond to the data in the table you've shown?

Comment: For the sample data, what do you expect for the X axis, Y axis and stacking?  I would assume the X-Axis would be hours played, and the Y-Axis would be GameName, and stacking would be DeviceId?

Comment: Yes exactly @RobertMcKee

Comment: Its just a sample data I need to make response as it somehow. U can see the jsfiddle I have linked. @StriplingWarrior

Comment: Not an answer but a side note, the line `var currentMonthData = Device_GameDevices.Where(x => x.CreatedDate >= currentDate).ToList();`  you could remove the `.ToList()` because the where will return an Iqueryable that you can pass into `var gamesList = currentMonthData.Select(x => x.GameName).Distinct();` that your code doesn't have to actually enumerate the list until it completely needs it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Chart
{
    public string type { get; set; }
}

public class Title
{
    public string text { get; set; }
}

public class XAxis
{
    public List<string> categories { get; set; } 
}

public class Title2
{
    public string text { get; set; }
}

public class YAxis
{
    public int min { get; set; }
    public Title2 title { get; set; }
}

public class Legend
{
    public bool reversed { get; set; }
}

public class Series
{
    public string stacking { get; set; }
}

public class PlotOptions
{
    public Series series { get; set; }
}

public class Series2
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public List<double> data { get; set; } 
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Chart chart { get; set; }
    public Title title { get; set; }
    public XAxis xAxis { get; set; }
    public YAxis yAxis { get; set; }
    public Legend legend { get; set; }
    public PlotOptions plotOptions { get; set; }
    public List<Series2> series { get; set; } 
}

void Main()
{
  var Device_GameDevices = new[] {
    new {ID=1,CreatedDate=DateTime.Parse("8/23/2017 06:07:30"),DeviceID="Desktop12",EndTime=DateTime.Parse("8/23/2017 06:06:30"),GameName="CyberGunner",StartTime=DateTime.Parse("8/23/2017 06:03:45")},
    new {ID=2,CreatedDate=DateTime.Parse("8/23/2017 07:14:01"),DeviceID="A12"      ,EndTime=DateTime.Parse("8/23/2017 11:14:01"),GameName="Marriage"   ,StartTime=DateTime.Parse("8/23/2017 07:14:01")},
    new {ID=3,CreatedDate=DateTime.Parse("8/23/2017 07:14:02"),DeviceID="A12"      ,EndTime=DateTime.Parse("8/23/2017 08:14:01"),GameName="Marriage"   ,StartTime=DateTime.Parse("8/23/2017 07:14:02")},
    new {ID=4,CreatedDate=DateTime.Parse("8/23/2017 09:14:01"),DeviceID="A12"      ,EndTime=DateTime.Parse("8/23/2017 09:14:01"),GameName="Chess"      ,StartTime=DateTime.Parse("8/23/2017 07:14:03")},
    new {ID=5,CreatedDate=DateTime.Parse("8/23/2017 07:14:03"),DeviceID="A12"      ,EndTime=DateTime.Parse("8/23/2017 10:14:01"),GameName="Marriage"   ,StartTime=DateTime.Parse("8/23/2017 07:14:03")},
    new {ID=6,CreatedDate=DateTime.Parse("8/23/2017 09:57:28"),DeviceID="B12"      ,EndTime=DateTime.Parse("8/23/2017 10:57:28"),GameName="Marriage"   ,StartTime=DateTime.Parse("8/23/2017 09:57:28")},
  };
  DateTime currentDate=DateTime.UtcNow.Date.AddDays(-30);
  var currentMonthData=Device_GameDevices
    .Where(x=>x.CreatedDate>=currentDate)
    .ToList();

  // Get total game list
  var gamesList=currentMonthData
    .Select(x=>x.GameName)
    .Distinct()
    .ToList();

  var chart=new RootObject
  {
    chart=new Chart{ type="bar"},
    title=new Title{ text="My title" },
    xAxis=new XAxis { categories=gamesList },
    yAxis=new YAxis { min=0, title=new Title2 {text="Total Game Time"}},
    legend=new Legend {reversed=true},
    plotOptions=new PlotOptions { series=new Series {stacking="normal"}},
    series=currentMonthData
      .GroupBy(d=>new {d.DeviceID,d.GameName})
      .Select(d=>new {
        DeviceID=d.Key.DeviceID,
        GameName=d.Key.GameName,
        HoursPlayed=d.Sum(x=>(x.EndTime - x.StartTime).TotalMinutes)/60
      })
      .GroupBy(d=>d.DeviceID)
      .Select(d=>new Series2 {
        name=d.Key,
        data=gamesList
          .GroupJoin(d,a=>a,b=>b.GameName,(a,b)=>new {GameName=a,HoursPlayed=b.Sum(z=>z.HoursPlayed)})
          .OrderBy(x=>gamesList.IndexOf(x.GameName))
          .Select(x=>x.HoursPlayed)
          .ToList()
      }).ToList()
  };
  chart.Dump();
}
```

This is how the series looks:

[image]

Comment: I was hoping if someway I could get the games value 0 for device where game has not been played using LINQ query. For instance, In B12 Device, there is no chess game and Cyber Gunner game

Comment: Have u seen the http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/bar-stacked/ mate?

Comment: Yes, when you are done, you can serialize the chart object and feed it to Highcharts.  Just creating a test project to verify the exact syntax.  Should be done in a few minutes.

Comment: Mate can u send me whole linq query code u have used there after GroupJoin ... . Getting some error.

Comment: I've changed the answer to the linqpad code I used to verify the data.  You will likely have to force the thread culture to en-US or change the sample dates to fit your culture to get the same results.

Comment: Thanks mate for your help. But still need to use for loop to get the data. But thanks alot.

Comment: For loop to get what data?  So long as `Device_GameDevices` returns the data you've shown in your sample, then you don't need any for loops that I can see.

Comment: As per sample as http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/bar-stacked/ here, I think I need for loop as I need object like series: [{
    name: 'Marriage' // game name,
    data: [1, 2, 3] // Sample Data according to device
}, 
 ...]. But I will try it.

Comment: If you serialize that by doing `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(chart).Dump();` you get `{"chart":{"type":"bar"},"title":{"text":"My title"},"xAxis":{"categories":["CyberGunner","Marriage","Chess"]},"yAxis":{"min":0,"title":{"text":"Total Game Time"}},"legend":{"reversed":true},"plotOptions":{"series":{"stacking":"normal"}},"series":[{"name":"Desktop12","data":[0.04583333333333333,0.0,0.0]},{"name":"A12","data":[0.0,7.9991666666666674,1.9994444444444446]},{"name":"B12","data":[0.0,1.0,0.0]}]}` which is exactly what highchart wants.

Comment: You can also return this as a JsonResult from MVC, and then you can feed it directly to HighChart, or you can just render the Json directly into the webpage if you'd prefer that.  I'm not familiar with HighCharts, but I assume it can take a list of double, but you could change the model to only return ints if it doesn't.

Comment: Just to give credit where due, I created the model by going to http://json2csharp.com/ and pasting the sample json from http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/bar-stacked/ into it.  I didn't make any modifications to the classes it output.  The code in main just fills out the classes as needed so it can be serialized exactly the way highchart expects.

Comment: No problem, just make sure to make this answer as correct.

Comment: Just on a quick note, I missed that I wanted the result this way. http://jsfiddle.net/0kL8tvmx/ instead of http://jsfiddle.net/xh7jmsgk/ !